# Nested syntax with PostCSS for :hover and :focus

Tags: css, postcss, tailwind-css, postcss-import

I'm using TailwindCSS and PostCSS and I have this css code:

```css
.btn {
  @apply py-1;
  @apply px-4;
  @apply border;
  @apply rounded;
}

.btn:hover {
  @apply bg-white text-black;
}

.btn:focus {
  @apply bg-black text-white;
}
```

Is there a native way in PostCSS (or with a plugin) to write this code like the below?

```css
.btn {
  @apply py-1;
  @apply px-4;
  @apply border;
  @apply rounded;

  &:hover {
    @apply bg-white text-black;
  }
  
  &:focus {
    @apply bg-black text-white;
  }
}
```

Comment: search how to use postcss with sass

Comment: something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-sass

Comment: I'm not using SASS!

Comment: yeah, but you will need add a plugin

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/front-end/postcss-sass-new-play-date here is an article about this that could help

Answer (score 2):

Use [postcss-preset-env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env).

First install, `npm install postcss-preset-env --save-dev`.

Then enable `nesting-rules` in your `postcss.config.js` file,

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "tailwindcss",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          "nesting-rules": true,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Here you can find the [list of features ID](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/blob/master/src/lib/plugins-by-id.js#L36) that can be enabled

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [postcss-nested](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested) plugin.

In your `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8.2.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.5"
  }
}
```

In your `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works too, following the object notation [Reference](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10117)

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
        'postcss-preset-env': { stage: 2 },
    },
}
```